# PHP best way to search a string for values in an array?

Tags: php

I have a string and an array, the array contains all kinds of parts of a string I want to find in the original string (this is for basically reading a error log and identifying what line there is a "Could not find", or "Error", etc.)

Is the foreach preg_match the best method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and speediest way is using [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos). If it returns `FALSE` it didn't find the substring, otherwise it did. Make sure you use `===` as it might return `0`:

```
$found_substring = (strpos($text, $substring) !== FALSE);
```

For case-insensitivity, use [stripos()](http://php.net/stripos). If you need more matching power, use [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match).

Comment: So the best method would be to loop through the array and do strpos for each array key?